# grep unicode 16 support

Tags: linux, unicode, utf-8, grep, utf-16

I use TextEdit on macosx created two files, same contents with different encodings, then

```
grep xxx filename_UTF-16
```

nothing

```
grep xxx filename_UTF-8
```

xxxxxxx
xxxxxxyyyyyy

```
grep did not support UTF-16?
```

Comment: This should be moved to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grepping binary files and UTF16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752913/grepping-binary-files-and-utf16)

Comment: I would like to also add that you could probably write a C program to search the files for strings in the time it took to post and look for answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 yourfile | grep xxx
```

Answer (score 4):

You could always try converting first to utf-8:

```
iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 filename | grep xxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ripgrep` utility](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) instead of `grep` which can support grepping UTF-16 files. Install by: [`brew install ripgrep`](https://brew.sh/).

Then run:

```
rg xxx filename_UTF-16
```

> ripgrep supports searching files in text encodings other than UTF-8, such as UTF-16, latin-1, GBK, EUC-JP, Shift_JIS and more. (Some support for automatically detecting UTF-16 is provided. Other text encodings must be specifically specified with the `-E`/`--encoding flag.`)

Comment: This is the best solution if you need to recursively search a directory: `rg -E UTF-16 <PATTERN> <PATH>`

Answer (score -1):

Define the following Ruby's shell function:

```
grep16() { ruby -e "puts File.open('$2', mode:'rb:BOM|UTF-16LE').readlines.grep(Regexp.new '$1'.encode(Encoding::UTF_16LE))"; }
```

Then use it as:

```
grep16 xxx filename_UTF-16
```

See: [How to use Ruby's readlines.grep for UTF-16 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54729247/55075)

For more suggestions, check: [grepping binary files and UTF16](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3752913/55075)