# Unable to grep output of python program, possible utf-16

Tags: python, grep, utf-16

I wrote a basic python program to parse android's resources.arsc. it prints out all strings found in the file. The strings have a zero value byte in between each character. This suggests to me that the strings are stored in utf-16. I don't know if that is correct, but android strings are localizable so I think it is. I am using string.decode('hex') to print the string out in human readable format. Here's a sample with a list of bytes that make up the string:

```
>>> print ''.join(['00', '72', '00', '65', '00', '73', '00', '2f', '00', '64', '00', '72',    '00', '61', '00', '77', '00', '61', '00', '62', '00', '6c', '00', '65', '00', '2f', '00', '61', '00', '62', '00', '6f', '00', '75', '00', '74', '00', '2e', '00', '70', '00', '6e', '00', '67', '00', '00', '00']).decode('hex')
res/drawable/about.png
```

The issue is, when I pipe this program to grep, I cannot grep for any of the strings read. How can I print it out to the shell so that grep will be able to match in its output? Thanks!

(EDIT) I did indeed print the string, but in my example I thought it would be better to show both the 'print'ed version and the returned version. sorry for the confusion. In this example, it is the '/res/drawable/about.png' that cannot be grepped.

(EDIT2) a simple demonstration:

```
11:33 AM ~/learning_python $ python -c "print ''.join(['00', '72', '00', '65', '00', '73', '00', '2f', '00', '64', '00', '72',    '00', '61', '00', '77', '00', '61', '00', '62', '00', '6c', '00', '65', '00', '2f', '00', '61', '00', '62', '00', '6f', '00', '75', '00', '74', '00', '2e', '00', '70', '00', '6e', '00', '67', '00', '00', '00']).decode('hex')"
res/drawable/about.png
11:33 AM ~/learning_python $ python -c "print ''.join(['00', '72', '00', '65', '00', '73', '00', '2f', '00', '64', '00', '72',    '00', '61', '00', '77', '00', '61', '00', '62', '00', '6c', '00', '65', '00', '2f', '00', '61', '00', '62', '00', '6f', '00', '75', '00', '74', '00', '2e', '00', '70', '00', '6e', '00', '67', '00', '00', '00']).decode('hex')" | grep about
11:33 AM ~/learning_python $
```

(EDIT3) another demonstration, I think this proves the data is in utf-16-be:

```
11:33 AM ~/learning_python $ python -c "print ''.join(['00', '72', '00', '65', '00', '73', '00', '2f', '00', '64', '00', '72',    '00', '61', '00', '77', '00', '61', '00', '62', '00', '6c', '00', '65', '00', '2f', '00', '61', '00', '62', '00', '6f', '00', '75', '00', '74', '00', '2e', '00', '70', '00', '6e', '00', '67', '00', '00', '00']).decode('hex')" > testfile
11:35 AM ~/learning_python $ iconv -f utf16be -t utf8 testfile
res/drawable/about.png
11:35 AM ~/learning_python $ iconv -f utf16be -t utf8 testfile | grep about
Binary file (standard input) matches
11:35 AM ~/learning_python $ iconv -f utf16be -t utf8 testfile | grep -a about
res/drawable/about.png
```

Comment: Did you "print" the decoded string?

Comment: Yes, that's how the final string was produced. I edited my question for clarity.

Comment: put all in an array and you will notice the prob   python -c "print [''.join(['00', '72', '00', '65', '00', '73', '00', '2f', '00', '64', '00', '72',    '00', '61', '00', '77', '00', '61', '00', '62', '00', '6c', '00', '65', '00', '2f', '00', '61', '00', '62', '00', '6f', '00', '75', '00', '74', '00', '2e', '00', '70', '00', '6e', '00', '67', '00', '00', '00']).decode('hex')]"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grepping binary files and UTF16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752913/grepping-binary-files-and-utf16)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode the characters:

```
'\x00r\x00e\x00s'.decode('utf-16-be') # produces u'res'
```

Then you can print out the decoded string:

```
$ python -c "print ''.join(['00', '72', '00', '65', '00', '73', '00', '2f', '00', '64', '00', '72',    '00', '61', '00', '77', '00', '61', '00', '62', '00', '6c', '00', '65', '00', '2f', '00', '61', '00', '62', '00', '6f', '00', '75', '00', '74', '00', '2e', '00', '70', '00', '6e', '00', '67', '00', '00', '00', '00']).decode('hex').decode('utf-16-be').rstrip('\0')" | grep about
res/drawable/about.png
```

Comment: Thanks for that... I can now grep the output of my program, but I have to use the -a switch. I can live with that :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ripgrep` utility](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) instead of `grep` which can support UTF-16 files.

> ripgrep supports searching files in text encodings other than UTF-8, such as UTF-16, latin-1, GBK, EUC-JP, Shift_JIS and more. (Some support for automatically detecting UTF-16 is provided. Other text encodings must be specifically specified with the `-E`/`--encoding flag.`).

Example syntax:

```
rg sometext file
```