# Removing unwanted characters and empty lines with SED, TR or/and awk

Tags: shell, awk, sed, hex, tr

I need to remove some unknown characters and remaining empty lines from a file, it should be simple and I'm feeling really stupid that I couldn't do it yet.

Here's the file contents (readable):

```
    136;2014-09-07 13:41:25;2014-09-07 13:41:55
    136;2014-09-07 13:41:55;2014-09-07 13:42:25
    136;2014-09-07 13:42:25;2014-09-07 13:42:55
    (empty line)
    (empty line)
```

For some reason, this file comes with several unwanted/unknown chars. The HEX is:

```
    fffe 3100 3300 3600 3b00 3200 3000 3100 3400 2d00 3000 3900  :..1.3.6.;.2.0.1.4.-.0.9.
    2d00 3000 3700 2000 3100 3300 3a00 3400 3100 3a00 3200 3500  :-.0.7. .1.3.:.4.1.:.2.5.
    3b00 3200 3000 3100 3400 2d00 3000 3900 2d00 3000 3700 2000  :;.2.0.1.4.-.0.9.-.0.7. .
    3100 3300 3a00 3400 3100 3a00 3500 3500 0d00 0a00 3100 3300  :1.3.:.4.1.:.5.5.....1.3.
    3600 3b00 3200 3000 3100 3400 2d00 3000 3900 2d00 3000 3700  :6.;.2.0.1.4.-.0.9.-.0.7.
    2000 3100 3300 3a00 3400 3100 3a00 3500 3500 3b00 3200 3000  : .1.3.:.4.1.:.5.5.;.2.0.
    3100 3400 2d00 3000 3900 2d00 3000 3700 2000 3100 3300 3a00  :1.4.-.0.9.-.0.7. .1.3.:.
    3400 3200 3a00 3200 3500 0d00 0a00 3100 3300 3600 3b00 3200  :4.2.:.2.5.....1.3.6.;.2.
    3000 3100 3400 2d00 3000 3900 2d00 3000 3700 2000 3100 3300  :0.1.4.-.0.9.-.0.7. .1.3.
    3a00 3400 3200 3a00 3200 3500 3b00 3200 3000 3100 3400 2d00  ::.4.2.:.2.5.;.2.0.1.4.-.
    3000 3900 2d00 3000 3700 2000 3100 3300 3a00 3400 3200 3a00  :0.9.-.0.7. .1.3.:.4.2.:.
    3500 3500 0d00 0a00 0000 0d00 0a00                           :5.5...........
```

So, as you can see the first 2 bytes are xFF and xFE and there are many x00 after each char. The line endings are a join of 0D00 + 0A00, carriage return and linefeed (`\r\n`) plus the x00.

I wanted to remove those x00 and the first 2 bytes `xFFxFE` and the last 4, and convert the `CRLF` to `LF`.

I could do that by using head, tail and tr:

```
    tr -d '\15\00' < 2014.log | tail -c +3 | head -c -2 > 3.log
```

The problem is, I'm not sure if the file will always arrive like this, so I need to build a more generic method. I ended up with:

```
    sed 's/\xFF\xFE//g; s/\x00//g; s/\x0D//g' 2014.log > 2.log
    or
    tr -d '\377\376\00\15' < 2014.log > 2.log
```

Now I need to remove the last two empty lines, which as I said in the beginning, should be easy, but I can't accomplish that.

I've tried:

```
    sed '/^\s*$/d'
    sed '/^$/d'
    awk 'NF > 0'
    egrep -v "^$"
    Other stuff
```

But in the end it removes only one of the blank lines, I still have one x0A in the end. I tried to replace the join of two x0Ax0A with sed, even using \n\n but it didn't work.
I can't remove all `\n` because I need the normal lines, I just want to remove when they appear at least two times in sequence. Again I could use tail or head to remove it, but I would be assuming that all files would arrive that way, and its not true.

I see it as a simple find and replace stuff, but it seems it doesn't work that way when we are working with linefeeds.

For information purposes:

```
    file -i 2014-09-07-13-46-51.log
    2014-09-07-13-46-51.log: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

Its not been recognized as a text file... this file is extracted from a flash shared object (`.sol`).

As the new files may not be like this and arrived as normal text files, I can't simple cut the files, but I need to treat those who are problematic.

Comment: That looks like UTF-16 with a BOM. Try opening the file in something that can handle that encoding. Then see if you can convert it to a better encoding for your purposes.

Comment: I think you're right, it seems to be an UTF-16 with BOM, I tried to convert it first: iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8, it removed those first bytes and the 00, but the last bytes gets messed, maybe the file comes corrupted, 0d 0a00 0d0a

Comment: What is the "corruption" exactly? There does appear to be a random `NUL` character in there that I'm not sure about that could be throwing things off I guess. Recreating that file here seems to convert correctly but there is a random `NUL` byte on the last line.

Comment: Yes, there's a NUL (x00) between the last two CRLF - 0d0a 00 0d0a - no problem with that, I just need to remove it all from the file, empty lines plus this nul, and the last linefeed

Comment: It is simple enough to post-process the converted file to drop that set of three bytes from the end of the file.

Comment: Just to make it more clear, I have thousands of those logs files that I need to import and can't lose them, so I cant assume that all new files are gonna be the same, that why I'm trying to build a method that wont change files straight

Comment: I didn't see your last answer before I posted mine. The problem is that new log files may come 'corrected', I mean, with the right encode and no ending NUL chars or wrong linefeeds (it should be like this since the beginning, but unfortunately I already have thousands of those files to import). I can't cut the last bytes right away. Give me a minute, I will try to remove them and give you a feedbacxk

Comment: I'm sorry, my rep is low yet, so I have to post here. As the original question, it would be easy if I could just find-replace those last bytes. I tried again with sed: iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 2014.log | sed 's/\x0d\x0a\x00\x0d\x0a//g' > 4.log - but again, it doesn't seem to work with x0a - \n

Comment: I could made it, but I didn't like the solution... well, here it is: I convert linefeeds to another char with tr, then I remove the ones I want (those that appear more than once in sequence) and then convert it back: tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/||//g;' | sed 's/|/\x0A/g'

Comment: sed operates on a line basis so can't handle operations on newlines like that. Use a tool that can. awk with the appropriate settings of `RS` or `ed` or just about any programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow I solved the problem by that time but forgot to answer, so here it is!

Using only tr command I could accomplish that like this:

tr -d '\377\376\015\000\277\003' < logs.csv | tr -s '\n'

tr removed all the unwanted characters and empty lines, and it was really, really fast, much faster than the options using sed and awk

Answer (score 1):

The "fffe" at the beginning of the file is a byte order mark (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and for me an indication that you have a unicode type file.  In that kind of file 'normal' ascii characters are represented by 2 bytes.

In another stackoverflow question/aswer the file is first converted to UTF-8... ([grepping binary files and UTF16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752913/grepping-binary-files-and-utf16))

Comment: Thank you for the info about the byte order mark! As I told Etan on the other comment, I run iconv to convert: iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8, the file is more 'readable' - although it won't open properly on some editors because the ending bytes get messed: 0d 0a00 0d0a

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it, but really didn't like the solution. I've replaced all linefeeds with another character, like pipe (`|`), then removed then when I found two in sequence (`||`), and then convert pipes (`|`) back to `\n`

```
sed 's/\xFF\xFE//g; s/\x00//g; s/\x0D//g' 2014.log | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/||//g;' | sed 's/|/\x0A/g' > 5.log
```

-- @Luciano

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the ASCII characters out of the file you might try [iconv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv)

You probably can identify the file's encoding with [file -i](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file)

Comment: file -i 2014-09-07-13-46-51.log 
2014-09-07-13-46-51.log: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
The problem is that those files are extracted from a flash shared object (.sol), and its arriving corrupted already

Answer (score 0):

I *know* you asked for `sed`, `tr` or `awk` but on the offchance it will change your mind, this is how easy it is to get Perl to do the heavy lifting:

```
perl -e 'open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf16)", $ARGV[0] or die "Error reading $ARGV[0]: $!"; while (<$fh>) { s{\x0d\x0a}{\n}g; s{\x00\n}{}g; print $_; }' input_filename
```

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow and give you a feeback! I may have expressed myself badly, I don't necessarily need to use those 3 commands, I just need something  that do the job on debian