# insert '.' between all characters in grep regex and use in piped grep

Tags: regex, replace, awk, grep, pipe

I want to insert `'.'` between every character in a given input string and then use it as an argument in a pipe

I am doing one of the following:

```
tail -f file.txt | grep -a 'R.e.s.u.l.t.'
tail -f file.txt | awk '/R.e.s.u.l.t./'
```

How can I just type `'Result'` and pass it as the regex argument to `grep` when 
receiving input from a buffer created by `tail -f` by using additional `bash` default functions

Comment: I'm a bit confused; so you want to do `tail -f file.txt | grep 'Result'` and have it print out results for `R.e.s.u.l.t.`?

Comment: yes because I don't want to have to insert dots between every letter as it's a bit tedious when the matching word / sentence becomes long

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It seems a curious way of doing searching. Is it something to do with UTF-16 data?  The `-a` option is _equivalent to `--binary-files=text`_, and `-binary-files=TYPE` is _assume that binary files are TYPE; TYPE is 'binary', 'text', or 'without-match'_, so it would look for ASCII characters in a UTF16 file, where the other bytes would be null or zero bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tail -f file.txt | grep -a -e "$(echo Result | sed 's/./&./g')"
```

This echoes the word `Result` as input to `sed` (consider a *here-string* instead), which replaces each character with itself followed by a `.`, and then the output is used as the search expression for `grep`.  The `-e` protects you from mishaps if you want to search for `-argument` with the dots, for example.  If the string is in a variable, then you'd use double quotes around that, too:

```
result="Several Words"
tail -f file.txt | grep -a -e "$(echo "$result" | sed 's/./&./g')"
```

Answer (score 1):

The awk version:

```
tail -f file.txt | 
awk -v word="Result" '
    BEGIN {gsub(/./, "&.", word); sub(/\.$/, "", word)} 
    $0 ~ word
'
```