# Hexeditor for searching strings in utf16le on linux

Tags: linux, vim, hex, hex-editors

I am trying to find a simple hexeditor for simple string search. `hexedit` and `bless` are [good candidates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498197/need-a-good-hex-editor-for-linux), however the string based panel (on the right) is mostly ASCII based.

I would like to search for strings in a very large binary file in a flexible way (I used [iconv `utf16le`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752913/grepping-binary-files-and-utf16)) to find some interesting one. But I would like now to find the offset in the file matching those strings.

I know I can search for `K.E.R.N.E.L.B.A.S.E.` instead of `KERNELBASE` but that sound ridiculous.

Is there a way to use [vim + xxd](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/343/how-to-edit-binary-files-with-vim) ? Is there a plugin for [bless](http://home.gna.org/bless/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `:edit ++bin ++enc=utf-16le filename`, and use Vim's built-in search commands to locate the "interesting strings". Then, `:echo line2byte('.') + col('.') - 2` will print the (0-based) byte offset of the cursor position.

You can also get a (1-based) offset into your `'statusline'`:

```
:set statusline+=\ %o
```