# How does `grep` determine which files are "text"?

Tags: grep

This question pertains to the usage and inner workings of `grep`. If I issue `grep 'needle' *`, `grep` will search for `needle` within all *text files* of the current directory (e.g., http://www.linfo.org/grep.html). But what constitutes these so-called "text files", and how does `grep` identify these files?

For example, ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16, could all be considered to be text files, but `grep` does not search UTF-16 by default.

As for identification, does `grep` use solely the [file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_signature) at the beginning of the file?

Comment: I'm searching this for the word "binary_files": 
 https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c.  It's a lot to go through.  I *think* what you're looking for is around line 1483.  Symbols `nlines_first_null`, `buf_has_nulls`, and `file_must_have_nulls` may be of interest.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I like @Amy's approach of looking at the code as a source of truth. Although I would hope something like this (especially the question on which file encodings are included) would be included in the documentation.

Comment: @user4624937 you know what they say: code doesn't lie.

Comment: While grep's determination is likely accurate enough in many cases, only you can say that a file is text or not, and if so, what the encoding is. If you do want to grep a UTF-16 encoded text file, you can [convert it to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3781221/2226988) first and pipe it to grep.